# Create MinHeap Using PriorityQueue from HashMap Entries

Tags: java, hashmap, comparator, priority-queue

I am creating a *Min-Heap* using `PriorityQueue` populated from a `HashMap`. Where `Entry` objects of the `Map` are pairs of `Integer` & `Integer`.

And I'm implementing it with a help of `Comparator`. To use *Value* of `HashMap` for comparison.

My question is - How to make comparison of `HashMap` entries on *Value* of type `Integer`?

```
PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Entry<Integer, Integer> o1, Entry<Integer, Integer> o2) {
        return o1.getValue() - o2.getValue();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Defining a Comparator

Defining a `Comparator` using an *anonymous class* isn't a good approach.

Since **Java 8** which was released more than 8 years ago we have an alternative, or even a bunch of alternatives like in this case.

A simple and straightforward lambda expression:

```
Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> byValueAsc =
    (entry1, entry2) -> Integer.compare(entry1.getValue(), entry2.getValue());
```

*Note:* `o1.getValue() - o2.getValue()` - might cause overflow of `int` value, which will lead to incorrect results. `Integer.compare()` - is the proper way to compare integer values.

Java 8 static method `comparingInt()` from the `Comparator` interface:

```
Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> byValueAsc =
    Comparator.comparingInt(Map.Entry::getValue);
```

And the **most suitable** option it this case `comparingByValue()` from the `Entry` interface :

```
PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> minHeap = 
    new PriorityQueue<>(Map.Entry.comparingByValue());
```

#### Populating the Queue

To populate the *queue* with *entries* from a *map*, you can use a plain `for` loop:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry: map.entrySet()) {
    minHeap.add(entry);
}
```

Or make use of method `forEach()` from `Collection` interface invoked on the *entry set*:

```
PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(Map.Entry.comparingByValue());

map.entrySet().forEach(minHeap::add);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could combine the comparison by first comparing the value and then the key like so:

```java
final var queue = new PriorityQueue<>(
        Map.Entry.<Integer, Integer>comparingByValue()
                .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()));
```

Comment: *How to make comparsion on Value* - OP clearly says - they want to compare entries by *Value*. *Keys* are not mentioned at all.

Comment: It's nice to have a deterministic sorting.

Comment: I didn't misread the question on purpose. And after all, I corrected my answer.

Comment: The point remains: it **doesn't answer** the question: *How to make comparison of HashMap entries on Value*. If you entail *Keys* which is not required, it'll will cause unnecessary operation to be executed. I.e. you've introduced the redundancy which isn't good by itself.

Comment: And if some point in time implementation of the `Map` would get changed, let's say to `LinkedHashMap` so that entry set would be ordered, then the result of sorting the entries by *Value* should make the entries with the same value to be ordering accordingly to their initial order, but it would **not** be the case with the comparator you've posted in the question.

Comment: *I didn't misread the question on purpose.* Well... It fills like you've invented the problem statement for the pure purpose of farming the reputation, instead of providing a useful answer that targets the problem. If you still consider this question to be unclear, then consult with the information provided in the SO Help Center to learn what to do in such cases.